# weird behavior of tomcat and docbase

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am using tomcat 7.0.22

I would like the URL: `127.0.0.1:8080` to point to my webapp that is located under Project folder instead of `127.0.0.1:8080/Project/`

So I defined in server.xml

```
<Context docBase="Project" path="/"  />
```

This works on the first time that I start tomcat.

If I take the following actions:

1. Stop tomcat
2. Delete the war and the project folder
3. Move the war from the deploy server to the webapp folder
4. Start tomcat

Again - I have to type `127.0.0.1:8080/Project/` in order to reach the application.

If I, in addition to the above 4 steps do:

1. Stop tomcat
2. Start tomcat

It works fine and I can reach the application at `127.0.0.1:8080/`

What can I do to prevent the extra stop and start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems:

1. Don't put `<Context>` in `server.xml`. Instead, use the preferred deployment technique of placing your `[appname].xml` file into the `conf/[service]/[engine]` directory. For you, that probably means `conf/Catalina/localhost`.
2. Don't set the `path` at all, and don't set it to `"/"` if you are going to set it: the proper `path` for the root webapp is `""` (empty, not `/`).
3. Make the name of your `[appname].xml` to be `ROOT.xml`
4. Move your `Project` folder outside of Tomcat's `appBase` (the `webapps/` directory) and reference it using a fully-qualified path name as the `docBase`.

You could have avoided all the mistakes above if you had done only two things:

```
$ mv webapps/Project webapps/ROOT
```

...and remove `<Context>` from your `server.xml` entirely.

Oh, and you should upgrade Tomcat: you are currently 7 point-releases behind, and there is some good stuff in those seven little releases.

Comment: So you actually mean that I need to get rid of tomcat's Root folder, and instead to name my folder Root and that's it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, except that the folder name must be `ROOT` (all caps) instead of `Root` (case matters, even on case-insensitive filesystems.